# Installing a Git-hosted module with pip on OpenShift

Tags: python, pip, continuous-integration, gitlab, openshift

I have a project with a requirements.txt resembling this:

```
-e git+https://some.gitlab.com/some_group/some_repo#egg=repo
selenium
pywinauto
```

I made a source secret on OpenShift with my username and password and started the build. Cloning the project goes through, but cloning some_repo fails with an Error: "Can't find Username".

I'm a bit confused because the main project was successfully cloned with the credentials provided in the secret, but it doesn't seem like Pip is reusing those.

What's more confusing is that OpenShift seems to store the credentials in a .gitconfig file, that should be known to Pip:

```
I0107 15:35:14.756570       1 password.go:84] Adding username/password credentials to git config:
# credential git config
[credential]
helper = store --file=/tmp/gitcredentials.324456941
```

Any idea ?

P.S. I wanted to try with an SSHKey but for some reason the admins doesn't want to enable this option on the company's GitLab. And I don't want to put some credentials in the url inside the requirements.txt.

Edit : I have no problem with this on my workstation

Answer (score 0):

pip expects you to add the username and password as a part of the URL if you are not using ssh keys. You could set the secrets as environment variables and refer to them in your `pip.conf`.

```
[global]
index = https://$username:$password@some.gitlab.com/some_group/some_repo
```

Comment: Not sure about that, Pip is working perfectly with this conf on my station.